# Separate configurations for different environments on protractor

Tags: protractor

For example `local`, `qa`, and `production`.

Each of them has different URL. So I expect to contain something in URL. So I need to take some parameter from console where I run the protractor.

I run protractor like:

```
gulp protractor
```

in spring boot.

Each of the environments has different account name so when I run gulp protractor, I need to put account name as parameter:

```
gulp protractor local accountname
```

Is that possible?

Or do I have to create 3 different `protractor.conf` to run for each environment which has different methods for different methods?

Comment: You can always write three different gulp tasks that pass in different variables for baseurl, username and password. Example gulp protractor-local, gulp protractor-qa or gulp protractor-production

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using a gulp task that accepted an argument representing the environment.  You can configure gulp tasks to accept arguments using a tool like [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) and work with Protractor using [gulp-protractor](https://github.com/mllrsohn/gulp-protractor)

I used this to switch out the `baseUrl` in the protractor config.  Example:

```
const protractor = require("gulp-protractor").protractor;

gulp.task('protractor', () => {
  const argv = require('yargs')
     .default('env', 'local')
     .argv
  return gulp.src(path_to_tests)
    .pipe(gulpif(argv.env === 'test', protractor({
      configFile: 'path_to_config',
      args: ['--baseUrl', env.testUrl]
   })))
 ...etc
 .on('error', function(e) {throw e; });
```

Then I could run the tests using `gulp protractor --env test`